# Semantic UI - Mobile Scrolling Disabled Once Modal Opens (and remains disabled even after modal is closed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, semantic-ui

I am using Semantic UI `2.3.2`and having page scrolling problem on mobile, once modal is loaded the page scrolling function is disabled (even modal is closed after).

This behavior can even be experienced on official site https://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html just try to "Run Code" for any example modal, and then try to scroll page.

Searching through, I have already tried using `observeChanges` settings without any help.

P.S. You must check the link on mobile browser. I have tested on Android/Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this was a Confirmed Bug on Semantic UI `2.3.2` https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/6449

I have resolved it by downgrading the Semantic UI to `2.3.1` which has fixed the issue. So anyone facing the same problem can downgrade to resolve it for now until it's fixed in 2.3.2.

Comment: still a bug in 2.3.3 - downgrading to 2.3.1 as suggested fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by commenting out a line in modal.js.  I'm not comfortable doing it as I'm not certain of any repercussions, but it was the only way I could get it to work.  My version of modal.js is 2.4.2.  Here is the code:

```
 scrollLock: function() {
        // touch events default to passive, due to changes in chrome to optimize mobile perf
        $dimmable.get(0).addEventListener('touchmove', module.event.preventScroll, { passive: false });
      }
```

I commented out the line `$dimmable.get(0).addEventListener('touchmove', module.event.preventScroll, { passive: false });`

That line of code disables scrolling (module.event.preventScroll) when the user does a 'touchmove', which prevents the dropdown from scrolling.  Commenting out the line fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got scrolling to work by using the Formantic-UI [modal.js from their GitHub](https://github.com/lubber-de/Fomantic-UI/blob/f53a92ad71efcc52a5519d09206908fa994ffefa/src/definitions/modules/modal.js) as suggested in the [comment](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/6449#issuecomment-489019711) for the issue shared in the [answer by @Alyas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51231612/929516).

So, in practice in the index.html after the `<script src="lib/semantic-ui/semantic.min.js"></script>` I added `<script src="lib/formantic-ui/modal.js"></script>` and that made scrolling work.